# Android studio- disable donwload button/Activity when internet not availabe

Tags: java, android, button, google-cloud-firestore, disable

I have a download button configured in my app. When I click the download button when the internet is not available, the button is getting clicked. When the internet is available, this download activity begins and the file is downloaded no of the times I clicked when the internet was offline.

Is there any way I can disable by download activity when internet is unavailable by giving a message check your internet connection'.

MainActivity

```
public class Download_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseFirestore downdb;
    RecyclerView downRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<Downloadsmodel> downloadsmodelArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    DownloadsAdapter downloadsAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_);

        setUpRV();
        setUpFB();
        dataFromFirebase();
    }

    private void dataFromFirebase() {
        downdb.collection("Downloads").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult()){

                    Downloadsmodel downloadsmodel= new Downloadsmodel(documentSnapshot.getString("name")
                            ,documentSnapshot.getString("link"),documentSnapshot.getString("fileextension"),documentSnapshot.getString("uploaddate"),documentSnapshot.getString("icon"));
                    downloadsmodelArrayList.add(downloadsmodel);
                }
                downloadsAdapter= new DownloadsAdapter(Download_Activity.this,downloadsmodelArrayList);
                downRecyclerView.setAdapter(downloadsAdapter);
            }
        })

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Download_Activity.this,"Error",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }

    private void setUpFB() {
        downdb=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    private void setUpRV() {
        downRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.drecyclerdownloads);
        downRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        downRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }


}
```

Download Adapter

```
public class DownloadsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Downloadsviewholder> {

    Download_Activity download_activity;
    ArrayList<Downloadsmodel> downloadsmodels;

    public DownloadsAdapter(Download_Activity download_activity, ArrayList<Downloadsmodel> downloadsmodels) {
        this.download_activity = download_activity;
        this.downloadsmodels = downloadsmodels;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Downloadsviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(download_activity.getBaseContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.downloads_elements,null,false);
        return new Downloadsviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Downloadsviewholder downloadsviewholder, final int i) {
        downloadsviewholder.dName.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getName());
        downloadsviewholder.dUploaddate.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getUploaddate());
        downloadsviewholder.dExtension.setText(downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension());
        Picasso.get().load(downloadsmodels.get(i).getIcon()).into(downloadsviewholder.dIcon);
        downloadsviewholder.dButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dowloadFile(downloadsviewholder.dName.getContext(),downloadsmodels.get(i).getName(),downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension()
                        ,DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,downloadsmodels.get(i).getLink());

            }
        });

    }

    public void dowloadFile (Context context,String filename, String fileextension, String destinationdirectory, String url){

        DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationdirectory, filename+fileextension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return downloadsmodels.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to check the internet connectivity

```
   protected boolean isInternetConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Inside your `BindViewHolder` use like this:

```
   downloadsviewholder.dButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                     if(isInternetConnected()){

               dowloadFile(downloadsviewholder.dName.getContext(),downloadsmodels.get(i).getName(),downloadsmodels.get(i).getFileextension()
                        ,DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,downloadsmodels.get(i).getLink());
               } else {

                    //Change your button color so it looks like disable if you want 
                }

            }
        });
```